# Location based chat and having chatrooms show up on map in Quickblox

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, quickblox

I have looked through the Quickblox samples and APIs but nothing really tells you how to make a location based chat app or have chatrooms be displayed on a map. I'm also trying to figure out how to link a chat room to a username if they decide to create one.